# control-dragging objects not working in case of a non File's owner type object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

So i'm trying to make connections between all the objects and the HomePwnerItemCell interface file(Name of the class file with which i'm supposed to make connections). Nothing is happening. I control-dragged the objects to the HomePwnerItemCell interface file for setting up the properties in the same, but its not taking effect. **I haven't set the HomePwnerItemCell as a File's owner**. What should i do?? I'm supposed to connect the HomePwnerItemCell ivars (by first creating them) to the objects in the XIB file. Not happening...  :?  :? It seems as if you cannot make such a connection unless you're using a File's owner. I don't understand..

Comment: Have you set up custom class to be HomePwnerItemCell in interface builder

Comment: If by setting up you mean making it a File's owner, then no.

Comment: Yeah.. No i hadn't renamed the custom class as HomePwnerItemCell.. Initially it was UITableCell. I just did that and now its working..